# Anyone knows about Akando Module and Dancer Module in Python?

Tags: python, scipy, bioinformatics

I am new to Python and got a assignment with **Akando** Module and **Dancer** Module

I wonder how those 2 modules works, do anyone knows any reference site about those 2 modules. They seems like under scipy and relavent with Bioinfomatics.

Comment: could you explain more detail? I mean do you have a list of functions that those modules contains. To be honest, I had the book while I dont quite understand this part.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this chapter](http://bit.ly/LbLqAA), I believe `Akando` and `Dancer` are not part of scipy; rather, they are modules that were put together to support the examples and aid readers of the [Python For Bioinformatics](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Python-Bioinformatics-Bartlett-Biomedical-Informatics/dp/0763751863) book.

It appears you can download the [examples archive](http://www.jbpub.com/samples/0763751863/Kinser_Applications.zip) from the [book's website](http://www.jblearning.com/catalog/9780763751869/). The relevant files are `pysrc/akando.py` and `pysrc/dancer.py`.

---

*P.S. I know nothing about `akando` or `dancer`. The information above was gleaned from a [quick google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=akando%20dancer).*

Comment: Undoubtedly the point of these modules is fully explained in the book.